# MS Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 - Stop Key Clicking

Tags: keyboard, clicking-sound

My new MS Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 clicks when the spacebar is pressed.  All other keys are silent - as is my preference.  How do I stop the spacebar from clicking?

Answer (score 1):

You have to discover how is that space's bar mechanism. Most likely, it uses a long metal bar to function. You can use lubricant on that bar - a little - if that is the case. If the click comes from friction, it will go away. You have to take off the keycap carefully to not brake. Please look at its manual for tips about how to do this.

Comment: This answer worked for me. In my case the problem was not a clicking sound, but intermittently key presses of one key were not resulting in the output from that key on the screen. After carefully removing the keycap, I was able to see what was causing the problem.